# php ajax - auto refresh a div only if returned data is not empty

Tags: php, ajax

I am using bootstrap , php and mysql for an application . With this , whenever the users are logged in , the admin will post messages across to all users that will be displayed as an alert on the page . Below is my ajax code :

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    {
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#admin_message').hide();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#admin_message').show();
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#admin_message').show();
        }
    });
    var $admin_msg = $("#admin_message");
    $admin_msg.load("get_message_board.php");        
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $admin_msg.load('get_message_board.php');
    }, 10000);
```

Below is my alert holder holder

```
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="alert_holder">
<p id="admin_message" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px"></p>
</div>
```

**PHP SCRIPT :**

```
include './functions.php';

    $sql = "select message from msg_db3 where user_group ='".$_SESSION['active_user_group']."' order by id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $temp = return_results($sql);

    echo $temp['0']['message'];
```

Now i want to make sure that the div (with id='alert_holder') is hidden by default and shows up only if **echo $temp['0']['message']** is not empty .If it is empty , it should be hidden . Also the transition is a bit odd since it shakes the entire page while bringing the alert up on the screen .

Please advice on the above .

THanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
can you try with normal Ajax?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "get_message_board.php"
})
.done(function( data) {
console.log(data);
 if(data.length>0){
       $('#admin_message').show();
     } else {
       alert('not found');
     }
}
});
```

Check your response length and show if it's not null

```
success: function(data) {
 if(data.length>0){
   $('#admin_message').show();
 }
}
```

In php script you can change to

```
if(isset($temp['0'])){
 echo $temp['0']['message'];
}
```

Comment: Tried the above already , doesn't work . Seems like no one has any idea about the above issue , people are just looking at it and probably running away.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is with

```
complete: function() {
            $('#admin_message').show();
        },
```

This code will show #admin_message every time when ajax is completed.
if you remove this unnecessary part you can make only my first change with `if` detection.